# How to evaluate the second argument of Cases only once

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, date-and-time

I'd like to find a fast but readable way to achieve the following:

```
Cases[RandomInteger[{AbsoluteTime["2001"], AbsoluteTime["2003"]}, 1000], 
a_ /; a > AbsoluteTime["2002"]]
```

The correct result can be achieved much faster using `with`:

```
With[{d = AbsoluteTime["2002"]},
Cases[RandomInteger[{AbsoluteTime["2001"], AbsoluteTime["2003"]}, 1000],
a_ /; a > d]]
```

But this is not very readable. Is there a more readable way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could inject the value once with a [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) instead of `With`.

```
Cases[RandomInteger[{AbsoluteTime["2001"], AbsoluteTime["2003"]}, 
    1000], a_ /; a > #] &@ AbsoluteTime["2002"]
```

In V10, we can use named arguments, which is arguably [sic] more readable (and more typing):

```
Cases[RandomInteger[{AbsoluteTime["2001"], AbsoluteTime["2003"]}, 
    1000], a_ /; a > #time] &[<|"time" -> AbsoluteTime["2002"]|>]
```

One could use `Evaluate`, although this would fail if `a` has a global value.

```
Cases[RandomInteger[{AbsoluteTime["2001"], AbsoluteTime["2003"]}, 
  1000], a_ /; Evaluate[a > AbsoluteTime["2002"]]]
```

Protecting `a` with [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) is a possibility, albeit a little cumbersome.

```
Block[{a},
 Cases[RandomInteger[{AbsoluteTime["2001"], AbsoluteTime["2003"]}, 
   1000], a_ /; Evaluate[a > AbsoluteTime["2002"]]]
 ]
```

Answer (score 10):

I rather like the `With` construction and feel it's quite readable, but if you don't want to use it, how about:

```
Cases[
  RandomInteger[{AbsoluteTime["2001"], AbsoluteTime["2003"]}, 1000]
  - AbsoluteTime["2002"], 
  a_ /; a > 0
] +  AbsoluteTime["2002"]
```

or

```
Cases[
  RandomInteger[{AbsoluteTime["2001"], AbsoluteTime["2003"]}, 1000]
  - AbsoluteTime["2002"], 
  _?Positive
] +  AbsoluteTime["2002"]
```

or, with `Select`

```
Select[
  RandomInteger[{AbsoluteTime["2001"], AbsoluteTime["2003"]}, 1000] 
  - AbsoluteTime["2002"], 
  Positive
] + AbsoluteTime["2002"]
```

which are all 200 times faster than your original and about as fast as `With` (though not particularly readable either).

Answer (score 10):

For a different approach, how about a memoized version of `AbsoluteTime`:

```
at[x_] := at[x] = AbsoluteTime[x]

Cases[RandomInteger[{at["2001"], at["2003"]}, 1000], a_ /; a > at["2002"]]
```

Comment: I like this (+1); it is about twice as fast as the original. I wonder whether this meets the OP's readability requirement, though. This is similar to starting with a `With` definition except that here the definition goes in global namespace. Just defining the value as a variable (together with your `at` in the random generator) is about two times faster still: `d = AbsoluteTime["2002"]; Cases[RandomInteger[{at["2001"], at["2003"]}, 1000], a_ /; a > d]`.

Answer (score 6):

`With` is designed to address the issue you bring up. The way to make your code readable is pick better variable names.

```
With[{midPoint = AbsoluteTime["2002"]}, 
  Cases[RandomInteger[{AbsoluteTime["2001"], AbsoluteTime["2003"]}, 1000], 
    time_ /; time > midPoint]]
```